# Finding argmin in an 2d array for particular indexes

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2d numpy array

```
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6]
[7,8,9]]
```

I have two boolean arrays, one for column and one for a row.

```
a = [False,True,False]
b = [True, False, True]
```

Now given these two arrays I want to find the argmin in the 2d array of only those indexes where column and row both are true.
I can do it using for loops, but is there a 'numpy' way?
Thanks

Comment: What's "armin"? Can you please write the result for the given example or better write the solution with for-loops which we then can help you to convert to a "numpy solution")?

Comment: I am sorry for the mistake, I meant argmin

Answer (score 0):

This function solve your problem(get the index)

```
numpy.where(#Your Condition#) #for your example condition is a==b
```